# Adding target"_blank within php

Tags: php, html

I'm using a Wordpress theme and trying to use target="_blank" to make this link open in a new tab, but I am not sure where/how to place it. If you could add it in to the example below in your answer I would appreciate it. Thanks

*Note that I have tried the suggestions from the other similar posts and they have not worked so far with my theme. Because of this, I do not feel this is a duplicate post. Thanks*

```
<?php 
if(!empty($theme_options['feature_var_1_url_1']) ) {
echo '<a href="'.$theme_options['feature_var_1_url_1'].'">';
echo $theme_options['feature_var_1_title_1'];
echo '</a>';
}else{
echo $theme_options['feature_var_1_title_1'];
}
?>
```

Comment: It's `target="_blank"`, not just `target"_blank"`, and it's a property of the `a` tag.

Comment: it's not a property of php, it's a property of HTML `a` tags.  You would use it exactly the same way you'd use it as you did before;  in the generated HTML

Comment: Thanks, apologies for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<?php 
    if(!empty($theme_options['feature_var_1_url_1']) ) {
        echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$theme_options['feature_var_1_url_1'].'">';
        echo $theme_options['feature_var_1_title_1'];
        echo '</a>';
    }else{
        echo $theme_options['feature_var_1_title_1'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, I tried this but for some reason it still opens on the same page. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: hmm. that's weird.... Can you please `inspect source` and see how the browser converts the php to html?

Maybe you need to escape special characters or something. I'm not sure yet unless I can see what the browser does to the anchor link.

Comment: <div class="row">
        <section class="single-feature text-center clearfix col-lg-4 col-md-4     col-sm-4 ">
        
        <h3>
          <a     href="https://mycw29.eclinicalweb.com/portal2878/jsp/100mp/login.jsp"><div class="one"><img src="http://charlestonallergy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/fea_blue_one.png" alt="Patient Portal"/></div><div class="one_hover"><img src="http://charlestonallergy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/fea_blue_one_over.png" alt="Patient Portal"/></div>Patient Portal</a>        </h3>
        <div class="feature-border"></div>

Comment: The target="_blank" is not added to the final output unfortunately. That is weird.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas on how to get around this? Thanks!